# Как избежать дублирования кода adapter

Tags: android, listview, java, adapter

Как избежать дублирования кода adapter?

Создаю приложения, где есть два listLiew. Ниже представлен код первого adapter,  второй adapter точно такой же, но надо добавить несколько View элементов.

Как сделать, что бы один adapter подошел к обоим?

```java
public class AdsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private List<Ads> list;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    public AdsAdapter(Context context, List<Ads> list) {
        this.list = list;
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        **View view = convertView;
        if (view == null) {
            view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_layout, parent,
                    false);
        }
        TextView textViewAds = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewAds);
        textViewAds.setText(getAds(position).getAddsText().toString());
        ImageView imageViewPc = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imagePic);   
      
         Bitmap b1 =
         BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(getAds(position).getPhoto(),
         0, getAds(position).getPhoto().length);
         imageViewPc.setImageBitmap(b1);**
        

        return view;
    }

    private Ads getAds(int position) {
        return (Ads) getItem(position);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

есть три доступных способа:

- по старинке (можно, но не рекомендуется). Добавить в адаптер специальное поле булевого (целого типа), которое будет указывать, какое именно поведение нужно. В нужных местах добавляется if/switch. Если два адаптера отличаются одним view в getView, такой способ может быть оправдан.
- делегированием. Делаем два адаптера и один класс, который хранит общий функционал. В адаптерах просто пробрасываем вызовы к классу, отличающиеся методы реализовываем по месту. Плюсы: легче тестить, модно.
- делается как в предыдущем случае, только класс превращается в адаптер. Возможно, с абстрактными методами. От него наследуются два адаптера с нужным функционалом. Плюсы: при правильном подходе можно обойтись только двумя адаптерами, унаследовав один от другого и не делать три класса.

Answer (score 3):

Создайте 2-й адаптер класс наследующий от первого и в нем переопределите `getItem()`

Answer (score 0):

У вас есть несколько инстурментов для этого. Как минимум композиция и наследование.

Логику по генерации view всегда можно вынести в отдельный класс, экземпляр которого передается в ваш адаптер на этапе создания (см. шаблон Стратегия), в этом случае у вас будет лишь один класс адаптера.